# Construct super Poisson brackets on the coordinate rings of Lie super groups

Tags: quantum-groups, integrable-systems, poisson-geometry, supersymmetry, supermanifolds

On line 7 of page 61 of the book [a guide to quantum groups](https://books.google.de/books/about/A_Guide_to_Quantum_Groups.html?id=bn5GNkLfnsAC&redir_esc=y), a Poisson bracket is defined on $\mathbb{C}[GL_n]$ for every classical $r$-matrix as follows.

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and $r \in \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ is a skew-symmetric classical $r$-matrix. Suppose that
\begin{align}
r(v_i \otimes v_j) = \sum_{k,l} r_{ij}^{(kl)} v_k \otimes v_l,
\end{align}
for some $r_{ij}^{(kl)} \in \mathbb{C}$.

Define
\begin{align}
\{c_{i j}, c_{kl}\} = \sum_{s,s'} r_{s',s}^{(j l)} c_{ks} c_{i s'} - \sum_{s, s' } r_{ik}^{(s' s)} c_{s' j} c_{s l}, \ i,j,k,l = 1,2, \ldots, n.  \quad (1)
\end{align}
Here $c_{ij}$ are natural coordinates on $\mathbb{C}[GL_n]$. By using classical $r$-matrix
\begin{align}
\sum_{s} (r_{sj}^{(s_3s_4)} r_{ik}^{(ss_2)} - r_{sk}^{(s_3s_2)} r_{ij}^{(ss_4)} + r_{is}^{(s_3s_4)} r_{jk}^{(ss_2)} - r_{sk}^{(s_4s_2)} r_{ij}^{(s_3s)} + r_{is}^{(s_3s_2)} r_{jk}^{(s_4s)} - r_{js}^{(s_4s_2)} r_{ik}^{(s_3s)}) =0 
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
r_{ij}^{(kl)} = - r_{ji}^{(lk)},
\end{align}
we can show that the bracket defined by (1) is Poisson. Is it possible to modify (1) such that it is a super Poisson bracket on $\mathbb{C}[GL(m|n)]$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is done in the paper of Andruskiewitsch "Lie superbialgebras and Poisson-Lie supergroups", Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg 63 (1993), 147-163,   http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02941339 (the key result is Proposition 3 in that paper).

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know thank you very much for the reference. How to write the formula in  "Lie superbialgebras and Poisson-Lie supergroups" using coordinates $c_{ij}$ in the case of $GL(m|n)$? I tried but the formula I get didn't satisfy super commutativity. I asked this question in the [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261590/how-to-write-a-formula-about-super-poisson-bracket-in-terms-of-coordinates).

Comment: @JianrongLi it would help to know what exactly you tried. Maybe you can include it in that new question you posted.

Comment: thank you very much. First I tried to verify the super anti commutativity. I tried to do the computations in another [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261606/how-to-proof-a-bracket-is-super-anti-commutative). But I don't know how to prove that 
\begin{align}
& (-1)^{|\psi||\phi| + |\psi||\mu| + |\mu||\nu| + |R_{\nu }\psi | | R_{\mu} \phi| + |\phi| |\nu| } = 1, \\
& (-1)^{|\psi||\phi| + |\psi||\mu| + |\mu||\nu| + |L_{\nu }\psi | | L_{\mu} \phi| + |\phi| |\nu| } = 1.
\end{align}

Comment: @JianrongLi Note that $|R_\mu\phi|=|\phi|+|\mu|$, because $R_\mu\phi$ is the result of $\mu$ acting on $\phi$, and action respects the grading. I think that this property, and the same for the right-invariant operators $L_\mu$, completely resolves your concern.

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, your answer solved my problem.

Comment: I tried to do computations in [the question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261590/how-to-write-a-formula-about-super-poisson-bracket-in-terms-of-coordinates). I obtained
\begin{align}
\{t_{ij}, t_{kl}\} = \sum_{a,b} (-1)^{|t_{ij}||E_{kb}|} r^{ik}_{ab} t_{aj}t_{bl} - (-1)^{|t_{ij}||E_{bl}|} r^{ab}_{jl} t_{ia}t_{kb}.
\end{align}
Is it correct?

Comment: @JianrongLi : I do not have time to double-check this now, sorry about that! I hope you will be able to unwrap the definition fully.

Comment: it's fine. I understand. Thank you very much for helping me about this problem.